# How to put object files in a static library into output section?

Tags: c, gcc, linker-scripts

How to put all object files into a section? For example, i have `a.obj` `b.obj` `c.obj` and `main.obj`. where ``` a``b``c ```are in a static library `lib.lib`.

Now my linker script is like this:

```
 MYSECTION 0x1800000:
  {
  a*(*);
  b*(*);
  c*(*);
  main*(*);
 }
```

But I want to use library name in the input section, how to do it?

```
 MYSECTION 0x1800000:
  {
  lib.lib:*(*);
  main*(*);
  }
```

is not valid.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. An object file typically has multiple sections and you definitively don't want them all to be merged into a single one. And libraries are collections of multiple objects. And that depends on the linker, not gcc, which is the compiler/frontend.

Comment: Yes, I do. Because my embedded board have limit memory, i have to adjust their section into different address

Comment: You seem to have a missconception what sections are, how they are used. You typically have multiple sections in an object file as you have multiple memory areas in your device. That is not a matter of "limited memory". Did you even had a look at the object file's structure? Maybe you should first read the documentation about your toolchain. That should also include the syntax of the linker-control file.

Comment: It's hard to explain, i can't put all `.text` into a continuous memory, it's limit by some features of my board and it's out of my control. And it's not related to my issue. You can replace all `(*)` of `(.text)` in my example if you want

Comment: That contradicts what you write in your question. And there is not only a `.text` section. That is not even the only generated by gcc you want to put into Flash/ROM

Comment: It's just part of my linker script. What i want is use library name instead of object file name